# Info.plist build file cannot be found when trying to run iOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am getting the following error code when trying to run my iOS project.

Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/nicho/Im_Free/im_free/ios/Pods/Runner/Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a
script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Flutter  3.14.0-14.0.pre.405
Dart 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-185.0.dev) • DevTools 2.28.0-dev.12
Xcode 13.0

Any help is very much appreciated.

I have tried updating pods, cleaning build folder, ensuring flutter is up to date, and running flutter doctor, but no issues arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following possible cases that replicate this issue.

1. You need to check the info.plist file should be in the main project
   folder  now in any sub-folder you created after.
2. If your info.plist is already in the main folder, then you need to check the build shared project settings:

File -> Project share settings -> Change the settings to Legacy build settings.

Cheers.

Comment: Legacy build settings worked, thanks!!